# how to show up a value that is closest to or equal to the results of calculating the system with the database?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-2

I use Framework CI

I have two tables in the database. The first table is "A" and the second table is "B". In the table "A" there is a column "DIAMETER" containing numbers obtained from the calculation of the system by the user.

While in the table "B" there is a "STANDARD" column containing numbers that have been entered by the admin.

Then how do I show up the "STANDAR" number where the "DIAMETER" number calculated by the user approaches or equals the "STANDARD"?

```
In the database
```

Table A, column
Diameter
  2.5,  3.8,
     5.6

Table B, column
Standard
      3,
      3.5,
      4,
      5,
      6,

If the result of calculating the diameter of 3.8 is the result to be raised is 4, if the result is diameter 5.6 then the result will be raised 6.
The results that I expected top figures that approached the standard number or the same as the standard number

**My Model**

```
public function get_standar(){
$this->db->order_by('standar', 'ASC');
$this->db->limit('0');
return $this->db->get('B')->result();
```

}

**My View**

```
<div class="form-group has-success">
<label>Diameter</label>
<div class="form-group input-group">
    <input class="form-control" name="diameter" type="text" value="<?php echo number_format($getdata->diameter,2);?>" readonly="">
    <span class="input-group-addon">mm</span>
</div>
<label>Standar</label>
<select class="form-control" name="standar" id="standar">
<?php foreach ($standar as $stand) {?>
    <option <?php echo $standar_selected == $stand->id_standar ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ?> value="<?php echo $stand->id_standar ?>">
        <?php if ($getdata->diameter >= $stand->standar) { echo $stand->standar ;} ?>
    </option>
<?php }?>
</select>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxWBc.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBv0Y.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The following query returns the minimum standard diameter bigger or equal than the diameter you calculated:

```
$diameter = 3.8;

$sql = "SELECT MIN(column_standard), {other columns you need}
FROM table B 
WHERE column_standard >= $diameter";

$this->db->query($sql);
```

The query above returns 4 as result.

Comment: thanks for your answer, before i use framework codeigniter, can this be used?

Comment: Definitely, if you run this query on your mysql client it will work fine. You just need to replace the $diameter to a value on your mysql client.

Comment: What king of error are you getting? Can you provide some code related to you query?